# Steering wheel stays locked 97 Z3

Tags: bmw, steering-lock

My steering wheel stays locked even after car is started. Hard to turn key also. It's 97 manual transmission Z3. Been service regularly. It has 122,000 miles on it. I'm wondering is it hydraulic issue. I asked that because the key wouldn't turn it first and had to have it towed home. Now the key turns, I;e can start the car, but now the steering wheel won't unlock. Fluid didn't seem low enough to cause this problem. Haven't  added fluid yet tho.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It sounds like the steering wheel lock pin is stuck, which is not a hydraulic problem. I'm not a vehicle mechanic or locksmith, so I'll leave it to someone else to leave a proper answer.